# How can I use cubic bezier for scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-events

How can I use easing or cubic bezier for scrolling page with built in scroll in web browsers.

Like this: https://draft.co.jp/en/aboutus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a pre-existing JavaScript plugin. There are a million of these out there, usually named nicescroll or smoothscroll or something like that. [Here's one of the more popular ones.](https://github.com/inuyaksa/jquery.nicescroll)

Side note: As a user, I find smooth scrolling to be an extremely unpleasant experience, and am fairly likely to immediately leave a website that uses it.

Comment: Thanks for your help and side note.
According to your side note, I need to think again about it probably.